# XMDS compilation errors on El Capitan OS X from XMDS terminal

Tags: macos, math, gcc, osx-elcapitan, differential-equations

[XMDS](http://www.xmds.org) is a software package which allows to solve ordinary, partial and stochastic differential equations by compiling them to C and running them at the maximum speed allowed by local machine architecture.
Normally XMDS supports the GCC compiler with the GOMP OpenMP library.

I'm trying to install XMDS, but whenever I run it I get the following error:

```
Checking for program mpic++                              : 

/Users/dg813/Downloads/XMDS.app/Contents/usr/bin/mpic++ 
Checking for 'g++' (c++ compiler)                        : /Users/dg813/Downloads/XMDS.app/Contents/usr/bin/mpic++ 
Checking whether the compiler works                      : The compiler doesn't seem to work
```

I have Xcode installed, which should have brought gcc with it. I've tried installing gcc by hand according to [this](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/05/01/compiling-gcc-5-mac-os-x/) guide, but towards the end it just started returning '`no such file or directory`', when trying to run configuration commands for gcc.

Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: Try `xcode-select --install` to install the command line tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent Xcode does not install gcc anymore, rather it installs LLVM/CLANG as a c compiler.
You can install gcc with macports, or directly from sources. In both cases gcc will need to be bootstrapped with the clang compiler. You will need Xcode line tools installed.

UPDATE: I checked by trying to install MXDS on my machine, which incidentally is similar to yours: el capitan, XCode, etc.
g++, the c++ compiler appears to be working. That is an obvious alias for clang. It is the mpic++, which to my understanding is installed by XMDS that isn't working.
I replicated your exact error:

```
Configuring for MPI scripts...
Checking for program mpic++                              :     /Users/michelefadda/Downloads/XMDS.app/Contents/usr/bin/mpic++ 
Checking for 'g++' (c++ compiler)                        : /Users/michelefadda/Downloads/XMDS.app/Contents/usr/bin/mpic++ 
Checking whether the compiler works                      : The compiler doesn't seem to work 
Configuration failed.  Address the above issue to use xmds2.
Config log saved to  /Users/michelefadda/Library/XMDS/etc/xmds2/waf_configure/config.log

XMDS configure failed.  Check error messages above and report errors to xmds-user@lists.sourceforge.net
```

I'll attach my log to a mail to the developer, as they suggest.

Incidentally, it seems that the error which XMDS is reporting, from config.log appears to be due to an hardcoded path:

/Users/michelefadda/Downloads/XMDS.app/Contents/usr/bin/mpic++  -mmacosx-version-min=10.11   -I/Users/michelefadda/Downloads/XMDS.app/Contents/usr/include   ../test.cpp -c -o test.cpp.1.o
err: **dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/graham/Developer/xmds-mac/BuildScripts/build/openmpi-1.8.3/../../output64/lib/libopen-pal.6.dylib**
  Referenced from: /Users/michelefadda/Downloads/XMDS.app/Contents/usr/bin/mpic++
  Reason: image not found

Of course there is no User named "graham" on my machine. That is very likely the error. I have reported that to the developer.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've installed gcc via macports, but I'm still getting the same error from XMDS. Is there some reason why a macports install might not be seen by XMDS? Thanks!

Comment: Found the error: it is due to a programming error in XMDS, a fixed path which references the developer's own machine. I reported the error to the developer, I think that a fix should be coming.

Comment: further update: the newest (2.2.2-2 version) of the OS X XMDS installer corrects the error you posted about. Unfortunately XMDS is in its current state incompatible with the LLVM based MPI: other libraries are missing/incompatible.
The developer is aware of this.

Comment: Yep, can confirm that the newest version fixes this issue. Thanks everyone for the help.